# Exporting Python Data to Excel File on Sharepoint

Tags: python, excel

I have a dataframe that I want to export to an existing Excel file that exists online on my company's sharepoint. I have the following line of code to do this:

`df.to_excel(r'Path where the exported excel file will be stored\File Name.xlsx', sheet_name='Your sheet name', index = False)` 
The filepath starts with https and ends with a filetype .xlsx?web=1

Python of course doesn't recognise .xlsx?web=1 as a valid filetype so do I just ignore the ?web=1 at the end? This is what I did but get an access denied error. What do I need to do to be able to export to this file?

Edit: Filepath is https://companyname.sharepoint.com/sites/XXX/Shared%20Documents/07%20-%20LE%20(Loss%20Elimination)/02%20-%20Open%20(Current)%20Loss%20Elimantions/13%20-%20Material%20loss%20against%20BOM/Copy_Material%20Flow%20for%20HDW%20Euro%20When%20to%20FP.xlsx?web=1

Comment: `?web=1` , is not part of the file path ... we need to know what 'Path were the file is stored' looks like. Are you entering a URL or a UNC filepath to a mapped drive?

Comment: This is the full link: https://companyname..sharepoint.com/sites/XXX/Shared%20Documents/07%20-%20LE%20(Loss%20Elimination)/02%20-%20Open%20(Current)%20Loss%20Elimantions/13%20-%20Material%20loss%20against%20BOM/Copy_Material%20Flow%20for%20HDW%20Euro%20When%20to%20FP.xlsx?web=1 @JeffUK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The filepath starts with `https` and ends with a filetype `.xlsx?web=1`

That's *not* a path, that's a URL.
You cannot simply "save" to a URL.

There are Python libraries for working with sharepoint. For example [Office365-REST-Python-Client](https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client), [pysharepoint](https://github.com/dexterai-lab/pysharepoint) and [this one on pypi](https://pypi.org/project/sharepoint/), but the latter only seems to support *downloading*, not uploading.

Since `pysharepoint` is basically a front-end for [SharePlum](https://pypi.org/project/SharePlum/), you might want to look at that as well. It comes with [documentation](https://shareplum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: I've edited the post with what I believe is the filepath? It was just copied straight from the excel document. I'll take a look at that library though, thanks.

Comment: While the libraries are useful, I would start with trying to map a network drive to the sharepoint library, then you can treat it as a file and let the OS handle the rest.  (Not sure this works.. but I think it's worth trying!)

Comment: Thanks @JeffUK. Seems like a much simpler option but I get an error saying "Permission denied". Guess I need to authenticate it somehow...

Comment: @JeffUK This actually came up in a different stackoverflow answer. But it was commented on as "not working".

Comment: @XYZ123 Also look at the `pysharepoint` library to which I added a link. It seems quite easy to use.

Comment: @RolandSmith Thanks, I'm taking a look at it but not really familiar with programming so not sure what to do with it. Do I just copy and paste the usage example, edit with my own details then use my df.to_excel function again and it should work? I'm also not sure what the source/sink paths are supposed to be in my case.

Comment: @XYZ123 Save your excel to a file somewhere. That path is then your `source` path. The `sink` path looks like a "directory" (if you could call it that in sharepoint) where you want the document to go to on your sharepoint site.  Never used sharepoint, but this is how the examples look to me.